# How to add type constants to PDB debug information for a method?

Tags: c#, clr, debug-symbols, pdb-files, mono.cecil

In an AOP templating framework, I would like to have the debugger show concrete items substituting for template items in a method generated from the template. I can show the values of templated string, numeric and enum items by adding them as `ConstantDebugInfo`s to the method's debug information, and this works. However, I also want to have the debugger show the concrete *types* substituting for template types. Is there a way to do this? For now, I am forced to add types as string constants, which is better than nothing but far from ideal.